# Unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I am using an oracle table and have created a unique constraint over four columns. Can these columns within the constraint have NULL in them?

Comment: It seems to me that it is pretty trivial to find out the answer to this with a test. Can it possibly take more than a minute to do so?

Comment: Yes - you're right. But I have learnt other information from the answers that Vincent, Amber, and Shoover has posted.

Comment: You are right! Wow, you are right too!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

you can have NULLs in your columns unless the columns are specified NOT NULL. You will be able to store only one instance of NULLs however (no two sets of same columns will be allowed unless all columns are NULL) :

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (id1 NUMBER, id2 NUMBER);

Table created
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT u_t UNIQUE (id1, id2);

Table altered
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, NULL);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, NULL);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, NULL)

ORA-00001: unique constraint (VNZ.U_T) violated

SQL> /* you can insert two sets of NULL, NULL however */
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, NULL);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (NULL, NULL);

1 row inserted
```

Comment: If your table has 3 columns and you only want the first two to be unique, I'm not sure how this can be accomplished using this method.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Oracle allows UNIQUE constraints to contain columns with NULL contents, but PRIMARY KEY constraints cannot contain columns containing NULL values.  (Edited: was "... nullable columns...", but my example below shows that not to be true.  Columns in a PK can be defined as nullable, but cannot contain NULL.)

You cannot have a UNIQUE constraint and a PRIMARY KEY constraint with the same columns.

```
SQL> create table stest (col1 integer not null, col2 integer null);

Table created.

SQL> alter table stest add constraint stest_uq unique (col1, col2);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into stest values (1, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into stest values (1, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into stest values (1, null);
insert into stest values (1, null)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SUSAN_INT.STEST_UQ) violated

SQL> insert into stest values (2, null);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from stest;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          3
         1
         2

SQL> alter table stest add constraint stest_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
alter table stest add constraint stest_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2)
                                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01449: column contains NULL values; cannot alter to NOT NULL

SQL> truncate table stest;

Table truncated.

SQL> alter table stest add constraint stest_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);
alter table stest add constraint stest_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2)
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table

SQL> alter table stest drop constraint stest_uq;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table stest add constraint stest_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2);

Table altered.
```

Answer (score 2):

Two nulls are considered not equal in Oracle, so these columns can have nulls in them.

Comment: There is no truth in my case (Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production). I use multiple constraint throught two columns (nullable VARCHAR2 and NUMBER) and I CAN'T inser two rows with null and same number.

Comment: I think it is best to answer in these cases with an example as the others (and the accepted) answer. That way, it clears up questions and shows that your statement is valid. In this case, I think the statement is not true and the accepted answer also show exactly why it is not true.