# Unique index/constraint on 2 columns in same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing, constraints

I need to create a unique constraint/index on 2 columns in a table. One of these 2 columns can be `null`. My unique constraint/index needs to check if these 2 columns are not null then they cannot be duplicate.

Not sure how to tackle that, any starters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique constraint on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841388/unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a primary key and function-based index for this.  Here is an example:

```
create table t (
    id int primary key,
    x int,
    y int
);

create unique index t_x_y on t(x, y, (case when x is null or y is null then id end));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc0718e6ffd37371b1fa74006c61b383) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the NVL function on the column in the index/constraint.